# Never disable the numeric keypad under Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, numpad

Is there any way to tell Windows 7 to never disable the numeric keypad?

My keyboard is a Microsoft Comfort Curve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only guessing, but how about a program to remap keys on your keyboard.
Remap the *Num Lock* key to something such that if you inadvertently hit it, it does something other then disable the numeric keypad.

Comment: I heard one time there is a specific windows setting for this